# Rails Client Side Validations throwing TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to use the Client Side Validations gem to display form errors within a modal window (using Rails 5.1.4).

When an invalid entry is submitted, I get the following error in the Debugger:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ClientSideValidations.formBuilders[form.ClientSideValidations.settings.html_settings.type].add')

If I put a breakpoint at the `addError` method within `rails.validations.js` I can see that the correct error message is being issued, but I don't know why I'm getting the TypeError (no errors are being displayed).

**Controller**

```
def create
  @project = Project.create(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    else
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end

  end
end
```

**new.js.erb**

```
// Render the new form
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("form") %>');

// Show the Modal and Enable ClientSideValidations
$('#dialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('form[data-client-side-validations]').enableClientSideValidations()
  $('.first_input').focus()
}).modal("show");
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @project, remote: true, validate: true do |f| %>
   ... fields ...
<% end %>
```